# How to use the api WTSEnumerateProcessesExW?

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm trying to use the Win32 [`WTSEnumerateProcessesExW()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wtsapi32/nf-wtsapi32-wtsenumerateprocessesexw) API.

First / second parameters:

> WTS_CURRENT_SERVER_HANDLE to indicate the server on which your application is running.
>
> To return an array of WTS_PROCESS_INFO structures, specify zero

Third parameter: I want to enumerate the processes of the current session only.

Fourth parameter:

> A pointer to a variable that receives a pointer to an array of WTS_PROCESS_INFO

I'm confused about how to define the fourth parameter:

```
#include <WtsApi32.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "WtsApi32.lib")

HMODULE hWTSAPI = LoadLibrary(TEXT("wtsapi32.dll"));

if (hWTSAPI == NULL)
    throw std::exception("LoadLibrary failed");

WTS_PROCESS_INFOW* pProcessInfo = NULL;
DWORD dwProcessCount = 0;

if (!WTSEnumerateProcessesExW(WTS_CURRENT_SERVER_HANDLE, 0, WTS_CURRENT_SESSION, (LPWSTR*)&pProcessInfo, &dwProcessCount))
{
    DWORD err = GetLastError();
    throw std::exception("WTSEnumerateProcessesExW failed");
}
```

In the code above, `DWORD err` prints "The parameter is incorrect."

Comment: *`[in, out] pLevel` A pointer to a DWORD variable that, on input, specifies the type of information to return.* 0 is not a pointer to a DWORD.

Answer (score 0):

As 273k mentioned, modifying the parameter to a DWORD it worked correctly:

```
HMODULE hWTSAPI = LoadLibrary(TEXT("wtsapi32.dll"));

if (hWTSAPI == NULL)
    throw std::exception("LoadLibrary failed");

WTS_PROCESS_INFOW* pProcessInfo = NULL;
DWORD dwProcessCount = 0;
DWORD pLevel = 0;
if (!WTSEnumerateProcessesExW(WTS_CURRENT_SERVER_HANDLE, &pLevel, WTS_CURRENT_SESSION,
    (LPWSTR*)&pProcessInfo, &dwProcessCount))
{
    throw std::exception("WTSEnumerateProcessesExW failed");
}
```

Comment: `LoadLibrary(TEXT("wtsapi32.dll"));` for what ?

Comment: @RbMm what you mean? doesnt need it?

Comment: of course not need

Comment: @Natalia you are not using the `HMODULE` for anything, so there is no point in calling `LoadLibrary()`. Your code is *static linking* to `WTSEnumerateProcessesExW`, so the OS will ensure that `wtsapi32.dll` is loaded when the program starts up. If you want to load the DLL dynamically, you need to either 1) use the `HMODULE` with `GetProcAddress()` to retrieve a pointer to `WTSEnumerateProcessesExW`, or else 2) use your compiler/linker's **delay load** feature to link to `WTSEnumerateProcessesExW` statically at compile-time but load dynamically at runtime the 1st time it is called.